# Why i can't declare following function in Visual C++ "string timeToStr(string);"?

Tags: c++, function, declaration

When i'm trying to declare a function with a string parameter in .h file an error occurs. I haven't forgot to include string.h =) Everything builds fine when i'm using char[], but the i want the argument to be a string.

Comment: what error occurs? and have you tried std::string timeToStr( std::string ); while including <string> (ie no .h)

Comment: post some code, easier to see whats going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`string.h` doesn't exist in C++. Did you mean `string` (without the `.h`)? Additionally, the `string` class resides in the `std` namespace you need to qualify the type usage:

```
std::string timeToStr(std::string);
```

It would be helpful if you had posted the exact error message and a code to reproduce the error.

Comment: thanks a lot, i mentioned <code>using namespace std;</code> in my cpp file, but forgot about <code>std::</code> the header.

Comment: `<string.h> does exist in c++, since it is inherited from c ;). However, it has nothing to do with `<string>`

Comment: @Evan: yes but `<string.h>` exists only for reasons of backwards compatibility, it should not be used. Use the header `<cstring>` instead, it replaces `<string.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
#include <string>
```

instead of

```
#include <string.h>
```

they are different things - string.h is the CRT, string is the STL.